# Least writes sort for a linked list python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a linked list: `1 3 7 4 5 0 2 6`. I wish to sort it in the least number of moves/writes.

I can only move elements of that list using a function `insertBetween(element, after, before)` which simply inserts `element` in between the `after` and `before` elements.

For example, the first run might want to move 1 after 0 and before 2:
`insertBetween(1, 0, 2)`

The list will now be `3 7 4 5 0 1 2 6`.

Now it might want to move 7 to the end: `insertBetween(7, 6, None)`

The list will now be `3 4 5 0 1 2 6 7`.

Now it might want to move 0 to the start: `insertBetween(0, None, 3)`

The list will now be `0 3 4 5 1 2 6 7`.

The only priority for this sorting algorithm is the least number of uses of the function `insertBetween(element, after, before)`, since using it is extremely expensive. I wish to implement it in Python.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: How could it be very expensive? Sorting will be linear at least, if comparison-based *n log(n)*. So copy the items to a list, sort them there, then copy them back. Since it's Python, placing stuff in a list is really not expensive. It's more like copying pointers.

Comment: @Martijn_Pieters I'm not specifically looking for someone to write code, more of a name or further information of an algorithm if it exists.

Comment: @Ami Tavory The linked list data isn't stored in python, just the function I am using is.

Comment: @Tom321 I don't see why it matters. Make a list of proxy objects, sort that, then set the real list. I really don't see why the moves are important at all.

Comment: @Ami Tavory The problem I have is that there is no way of assigning the initial list to the sorted list. The only method of interaction with the data is using the function `insertBetween(element, after, before)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't focus on the elements you move. They can be moved anywhere and are not the problem. Instead, focus on the elements you *don't* move. Those need to be already sorted. So if you have N elements and a longest sorted subsequence with length L, you just need N-L moves to move the N-L elements not in that subsequence, and you can't do better. Finding the longest sorted subsequence is a standard problem, but [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of it like this, thanks. I can see that a max number of moves would be N-L, but if there are multiple sorted subsequences that occur whilst sorting, there must be an optimal way of sorting them. I'll have to create some toy examples.

Comment: *"occur whilst sorting"*? Not sure what you mean. I'd just first find a longest sorted subsequence, and then afterwards move all other elements appropriately.